# Перебор объекта в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Нужно перебрать объект с изображениями, добавляя css стили, .css() не подойдет так как нужно учитывать высоту каждого отдельно элемента.

```
var slickSlide = $('.rome-page-examples-slide img');
$.each(slickSlide, function(key){
    var slickSlideHeight  = key.height();
    key.css('top', 75 -slickSlideHeight/2);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`.css`**](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) вполне подойдет

```
$('.rome-page-examples-slide img').css('top', function(index,value){
    var objHeight = $(this).height();
    return 75 - objHeight/2;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.rome-page-examples-slide img').each(function(i, obj) {
    var objHeight = $(obj).height();
    $(obj).css('top', 75 - objHeight/2);
});
```